# How to resolve 'Potential Leak' issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks

I am using the 'analyze' tool in xcode to check for potential leakages in my app.

I am getting the following warning as a result.

[image]

How do I resolve the potential leak shown above? "self.answerArray" is just an array I declared in my header file

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've called `mutableCopy` on the array (which returns a new array with a retain count of +1 - You own it), and you assign it to a property (which I assume is a strong/retain property) and you're not releasing it. You're leaking the memory.

You should release `tempArray` after assigning it to the property - and ensure the property is released in your class' `dealloc` method.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize that mutable copy will increase the retain count. Thanks for the response

Comment: Anything with Copy, Alloc, Retain or New in the name is owned  by the caller, according to the conventions. I've always thought of it as the CARN rule :)

Answer (score 0):

You should either send retain/release to answerArray (release old object before assigning a new one, retain the new object), or, probably better, declare a property

```
@property (retain) NSArray* answerArray;
```

this way compiler will generate release/retain (on assign) for you. See [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html). Otherwise the object answerArray was referencing before the assignment (answerArray = tempArray) will remain dangling in memory.

In case you will use a declared property, make sure to add your temp variable to autorelease pool:

```
tempArray = [[self.answerArray mutableCopy]autorelease];
```

or just send it release yourself (right before it goes out of scope).